Run docker compose command for devcontainer
I like to setup up my projects with vscode devcontainers and a docker-compose.yml. I sometimes like to change some settings in one of the services and run some docker-compose commands from the cli (e.g. removing all volumes, changing the docker-compose.yml and updating with docker compose up -d).
Currently I do this by getting the docker-compose command from the logs and copying it with all the config files to the command line. Is there any better way to do this? I tried the devcontainer cli, but it's not working for my use-cases.
